# A specific installing problem about JuMP 0.18.6 in julia 1.4.2

Tags: julia, julia-jump

```
Downloading artifact: CompilerSupportLibraries
curl: (52) Empty reply from server                                            
ERROR: LoadError: Unable to automatically install 'CompilerSupportLibraries' from '/home/zyh/.julia/packages/CompilerSupportLibraries_jll/790hI/Artifacts.toml'
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] ensure_artifact_installed(::String, ::Dict{String,Any}, ::String; platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, verbose::Bool, quiet_download::Bool) at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Artifacts.jl:894
 [3] ensure_all_artifacts_installed(::String; platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, pkg_uuid::Nothing, include_lazy::Bool, verbose::Bool, quiet_download::Bool) at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Artifacts.jl:958
 [4] download_artifacts(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{String,1}; platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux, verbose::Bool) at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:616
 [5] download_artifacts(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux, verbose::Bool) at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:595
 [6] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux) at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1091
 [7] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:159
 [8] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:112
 [9] #add#27 at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:109 [inlined]
 [10] add at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:109 [inlined]
 [11] #add#23 at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:106 [inlined]
 [12] add(::Pkg.Types.PackageSpec) at /usr/local/julia/julia-1.4.2/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:106
 [13] top-level scope at /home/zyh/DOLPHYN_old/julenv.jl:20
 [14] include(::String) at ./client.jl:439
 [15] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
```

I'm trying to construct a specific environment using JuMP 0.18.6 in Julia 1.4.2. But when downloading JuMP, it seems that this problem got blocking my may. Had anybody ever encountered this before and have a solution?

Comment: are you behind a firewall?

Comment: I strongly encourage you to update to Julia 1.6 and the latest version of JuMP. v0.18.6 is unsupported and may not be compatible with the latest solvers.

Comment: I really want to, but now I'm developing a new project the previous version of which is based on JuMP 0.18.6. Older version has been proven effective, and I need to converge newer version with it. Therefore a working environment for older version demanding JuMP 0.18.6 is a must.

Answer (score 1):

it's likely due to firewall of some sort, if you're from China, try the mirror source:
https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/julia/